# conditional distribution for normal distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, conditional

> Assume $X = (X_1, X_2 , ... ,X_n )$ is observed, where the $X_i$ are (independently) $N(\theta , 1)$. Find the conditional distribution of $X_1,....X_{n-1}$ given $\bar{X}$.

I am having a problem in setting up the conditional distribution. Do I need to use multivariate here?

Can I start with this: $f(x_1,...x_{n-1}|\bar{x})=f(x_1,...,x_{n−1})/f_{\bar{X}}(x)$?

Comment: Yes, but start with N=2. It can help you understand the logic.

Comment: can I use this: $f(x_1, ...,x_{n-1})/f_{\bar{X}}(x)$

Comment: The links at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=conditional++normal+distribution+score%3A1+self-study+mean may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this, but a better way is trying to apply the known conditional distribution of multivariate normal distribution as follows.

To begin with, let's determine the joint distribution of $(X_1, \ldots, X_{n - 1}, \bar{X})$. Clearly, this random vector is a linear transformation of the observed random vector $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\
\vdots \\
X_{n - 1} \\
\bar{X}
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
I_{(n - 1)} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{n}e^\top & \frac{1}{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\ \vdots \\ X_{n - 1} \\ X_n
\end{bmatrix}, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
where $e = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{(n - 1) \times 1}$. In view of $(1)$, $(X_1, \bar{X})$ [has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation) multivariate normal distribution, with the mean vector
\begin{align}
\mu_0 = \begin{bmatrix}
I_{(n - 1)} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{n}e^\top & \frac{1}{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\theta e \\ \theta
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\theta e \\ \theta
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
and the covariance matrix
\begin{align}
\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
I_{(n - 1)} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{n}e^\top & \frac{1}{n}
\end{bmatrix}
I_{(n)}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{(n - 1)} & \frac{1}{n}e \\
0 & \frac{1}{n}
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
I_{(n - 1)} & \frac{1}{n}e \\
\frac{1}{n}e^\top & \frac{1}{n}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Now according to [conditional distributions of a multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions), it can be concluded that
$X_1, \ldots, X_{n - 1} | \bar{X} \sim N(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)$,
where
\begin{align}
& \mu_1 = \theta e + \frac{1}{n}e \times n \times (\bar{X} - \theta) = \bar{X}e, \\
& \Sigma_1 = I_{(n - 1)} - \frac{1}{n}e \times n \times\frac{1}{n}e^\top = I_{(n - 1)} - \frac{1}{n}ee^\top.
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, that's the way we have been taught.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1,\ \cdots, X_n$ be i.i.d random variables from $N(\mu,\ 1)$ (By a linear transformation we may assume $\sigma=1$.). $T=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$  Then we claim the conditional density function shall be
\begin{align*}
&p\left(X=x_1,\ \cdots,\ X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}\mid T=t\right) =\\ &\frac{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}})^ne^{-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2}{2}-\frac{(t-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i-\mu)^2}{2}}}{p_T(t)} \tag{$\star$} \label{claim-of-conditional-distribution}\end{align*},
where $p_T$ is the density function of $N(n\mu,\ n)$.

An intuitive explaination is as such: $T\sim N(n\mu,\ n)$ (well-known), and $X_1=x_1,\cdots, X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, T=t\iff X_1=x_1,\cdots, X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, X_n=t-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i$. Hence
\begin{align*}
&p\left(X=x_1,\ \cdots,\ X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}\mid T=t\right)=\\ &\frac{P(X_1=x_1,\cdots, X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, X_n=t-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i)}{P\left( T=t\right) }=\text{RHS of eq (\ref{claim-of-conditional-distribution})}.
\end{align*}

If you do not think the above argument is sufficiently rigorous, here is another approach:

\begin{align*}
&P\left(X_1<x_1,\ \cdots,\ X_{n-1}<x_{n-1}\mid T=t\right) \\
=&\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{P\left(X_1<x_1,\ \cdots,\ X_{n-1}<x_{n-1}, t-\Delta x<T<t \right) }{P\left(t-\Delta x<T<t\right) }\\
=&\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{\frac{P\left(X_1<x_1,\ \cdots,\ X_{n-1}<x_{n-1}, t-\Delta x<T<t \right) }{\Delta x}}{\frac{P\left(t-\Delta x<T<t\right)}{\Delta x}}. \tag{$\star\star$}\label{Shandong-University-Xu-Yuming-ge-ze-gang-du}
\end{align*}
Now $\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{P\left(t-\Delta x<T<t\right)}{\Delta x} $ is $p_T(t)$, the value of the density function of $N(n\mu,\ n)$ at $t$ since $T\sim N(n\mu,\ n)$. As for
$$\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0}{\frac{P\left(X_1<x_1,\ \cdots,\ X_{n-1}<x_{n-1}, t-\Delta x<T<t \right) }{\Delta x}}$$,
it equals
$$\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0} \int_{D}\ \prod_{i=1}^{n}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2}}\right)\ dy_1\cdots dy_n  $$
where $D=\{\left(y_1,\ \cdots, \ y_n\right)\ \mid\  y_i<x_i\ \left( 1\le i\le n-1 \ \right),\ t-\Delta x<\sum_{i=1}^n y_i<t  \}$. By a change of variable
$$ \begin{cases}
&\tilde{y}_1=y_1\\
&\tilde{y}_2=y_2\\
&\cdots\\
&\tilde{y}_{n-1}=y_{n-1}\\
&T=y_1+\cdots+y_n
\end{cases}
$$
with Jacobi determinant $1$ we have (we still use $y_i$ to denote $\tilde{y}_i$, to make it more readable):
\begin{align*}
&\int_{D}\ \prod_{i=1}^{n}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2}}\right)\ dy_1\cdots dy_n\\=&\int_{D'} \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2}}\right)  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{\left( T-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}y_i-\mu\right) ^2}{2}} dy_1\cdots dy_{n-1}dT
\end{align*}
, where
$$T=\{\left(y_1,\ \cdots, y_{n-1},\ T \right)\ \mid y_i<x_i\ \left( 1\le i\le n-1\ \right),\ t-\Delta x<T<t \}.  $$
Now apply Fubini's theorem,
$$\text{above}=\int_{t-\Delta x}^t\left( \int_{D''} \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2}}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{\left( T-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}y_i-\mu\right) ^2}{2}}  \right) dy_1\cdots dy_{n-1}\right)dT $$
, where
$$ D''=\{\left( y_1,\ \cdots, y_{n-1}\right) \mid \ y_i<x_i\ \left( 1\le i\le n-1\ \right)\}  .$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
&\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0}{\frac{P\left(X_1<x_1,\ \cdots,\ X_{n-1}<x_{n-1}, t-\Delta x<T<t \right) }{\Delta x}}\\
=&\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{1}{\Delta x} \left( \int_{D}\ \prod_{i=1}^{n}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2}}\right)\ dy_1\cdots dy_n \right)  \\
=&\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta x} \left( \int_{t-\Delta x}^t\left( \int_{D''} \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2}}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{\left( T-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}y_i-\mu\right) ^2}{2}}  \right) dy_1\cdots dy_{n-1}\right)dT \right) \\
=&\int_{D''} \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2}}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{\left( t-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}y_i-\mu\right) ^2}{2}}  \right) dy_1\cdots dy_{n-1}
\end{align*}

Now recall eq(\ref{Shandong-University-Xu-Yuming-ge-ze-gang-du}), we conlude
\begin{align*}
&P\left(X_1<x_1,\ \cdots,\ X_{n-1}<x_{n-1}\mid T=t\right)\\
=&\frac{\int_{D''} \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2}}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{\left( t-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}y_i-\mu\right) ^2}{2}}  \right) dy_1\cdots dy_{n-1}}{p_T(t)}
\end{align*}
, where
$$D''=\{\left( y_1,\ \cdots, y_{n-1}\right) \mid \ y_i<x_i\ \left( 1\le i\le n-1\ \right)\}  . $$

The above is actually the distribution function. We can easily infer the density function is
$$ p\left(X=x_1,\ \cdots,\ X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}\mid T=t\right) =\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{2}}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{\left( t-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i-\mu\right) ^2}{2}}}{p_T(t)} $$,
precisely what we have claimed.